# Devops Pipelines and Releases: Deploying One solution with multiple projects as one zip file/package

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Would like your opinion on how to do this. We have a solution with multiple projects. The solution needs to be deployed in only one website. At the moment, when I build my pipeline, the drop folder contains multiple zip files, one for each project.

This is the YAML for the Build task

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build MySolution'
  inputs:
    solution: '$/MyRepo/Main/MySolution/Mysolution.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

This is my YAML for the Publish task

```
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish ChilliDB'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

When I looked at my drop folder, I can see the following zip files

drop

- Project 1.zip
- Project 2.zip
- Project 3.zip

The problem is when I create a Release using IIS website Deployment template, I can only select one zip file from the drop folder to be deployed into the website.

Is it possible that in my pipepline build and publish tasks I will end up with my drop containing something like this:

drop

- My solution.zip

And then the My solution.zip will contain folders for each of the project files.

OR can I do something on my Release Pipeline that I can deploy multiple projects zip file into one website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to extract the project.zip file before publishing the drop. Check the example below:

```
steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\*.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\1"'

- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/1/WebApplication1.zip'
    destinationFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/2/WebApplication1'
    cleanDestinationFolder: true
    overwriteExistingFiles: false
- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/1/WebApplication2.zip'
    destinationFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/2/WebApplication2'
    cleanDestinationFolder: true
    overwriteExistingFiles: false

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/2'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Thank you for that.